# How is the copula $C\big(X_1, 1/X_1, \exp(-X_1)\big)$ equal to the copula $C(X_1, - X_1, -X_1)$ and what is its form?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, copula

Let $X_1$ be a positive random variable with a continuous cumulative distribution function and $C$ the copula of $(X_1, 1/X_1, \exp(-X_1))$.

Why is $C$ also the copula of $(X_1, -X_1, -X_1)$ and what is the form of $C$?

For the first question, we have by Sklar's theorem that $C(X_1, 1/X_1, \exp(-X_1)) = F\big(q(X_1), q(1/X_1), q(\exp(-X))\big)$, where $q$ denotes the quantile function of $X$ which is just the inverse of the cdf of $X$ since the cdf of $X$ is continuous. So this would imply that we would need $q(1/X_1) = q(\exp(-X_1)) = q(-X_1)$, but I can't think of a distribution for which this would hold.

Further, for the second question regarding the form of $C$, I was thinking maybe using the independence copula $\Pi(\mathbf{u}) = \prod_{j=1}^d u_j$ since then the minus of the second and third component cancel each other out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer follows from the comonotonicity/countermonotonicity of the variables considered. To see this, for simplicity consider a case with exact, continuous inverses. In this case we have by definition
$$\begin{aligned}C(u_1,u_2,u_3)=P(X_1\leq F_{X_1}^{-1}(u_1),1/X_{1}\leq F_{1/X_1}^{-1}(u_2),e^{-X_1}\leq F_{e^{-X_1}}^{-1}(u_3))
\end{aligned}$$
However
$$F_{1/X_1}(x_2)=P(X_1\geq 1/x_2)=1-F_{X_1}(1/x_2)\implies F_{1/X_1}^{-1}(u_2)=1/F_{X_1}^{-1}(1-u_2)$$
$$F_{e^{-X_1}}(x_3)=P(X_1\geq -\ln(x_3))=1-F_{X_1}(-\ln(x_3))\implies F_{e^{-X_1}}^{-1}(u_3)=e^{-F_{X_1}^{-1}(1-u_3)}$$
Therefore we get
$$C(u_1,u_2,u_3)=P(X_1\leq F_{X_1}^{-1}(u_1),X_1\geq F_{X_1}^{-1}(1-u_2),X_1\geq F_{X_1}^{-1}(1-u_3))$$
Now consider
$$\tilde{C}(u_1,u_2,u_3)=P(X_1\leq F_{X_1}^{-1}(u_1),-X_{1}\leq F_{-X_1}^{-1}(u_2),{-X_1}\leq F_{{-X_1}}^{-1}(u_3))$$
We have
$$F_{-X_1}(x_2)=P(X_1\geq -x_2)=1-F_{X_1}(-x_2)\implies F_{-X_1}^{-1}(u_2)=-F_{X_1}^{-1}(1-u_2)$$
So ${C}(u_1,u_2,u_3)=\tilde{C}(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ and we conclude for the first part. For the form:
$$\begin{aligned}{C}(u_1,u_2,u_3)&=P(\max(F_{X_1}^{-1}(1-u_2),F_{X_1}^{-1}(1-u_3))\leq X_1\leq F_{X_1}^{-1}(u_1))=\\
&=F_{X_1}(F_{X_1}^{-1}(u_1))-F_{X_1}(\max(F_{X_1}^{-1}(1-u_2),F_{X_1}^{-1}(1-u_3))=\\
&=u_1-\max(1-u_2,1-u_3),\quad u_1\geq \max(1-u_2,1-u_3)\end{aligned}$$
and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks so much, I think I understand the first part, but how can you see/did you know what the form of the copula is?

Comment: You're welcome @AtK42. For the second part, first note that $P(X\geq x,X\geq y,X\leq z)=P(X\in [x,\infty)\cap[y,\infty)\cap (-\infty,z])=P(\max(x,y)\leq X\leq z)$ if $z\geq \max(x,y)$ and zero otherwise because the intersection would be empty. The rest follows from the properties of inverse functions. Please let me know if you need more clarity.

Comment: So just to be 100% sure, in your argument provided in the above comment, we have $x = 1-u_2, y = 1-u_3$, correct?
And a meta question that maybe doesn't belong here, but should I normally @ you/someone who comments if only a single person has commented (apart from myself)?

Comment: @AtK42 No, in the argument above we would have $x=F_{X}^{-1}(1-u_2),y=F_{X}^{-1}(1-u_3)$. Then use the properties of the inverse to recover the final condition

Comment: Ah right, sorry yes of course, now everything makes perfect sense.

Comment: @AtK42 you're welcome!